# Difference between SQL Server and Oracle 'User'

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Are there any differences between a user in SQL Server and one in Oracle? If so, what are they?

Comment: @KM: can I fill both blanks with the same database, since any database has both kinds of users?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `Oracle`, the users and the schema are one thing. You can create two different tables with the same name, belonging to different users.

In `SQL Server`, schema and user are separate things. The users are only used to log in and define permissions.

See this question for more information: [What is the difference between an Oracle and Microsoft schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365368/what-is-the-difference-between-an-oracle-and-microsoft-schema/5420199#5420199)

Comment: Additionally, what is a `schema` in Oracle is a `database` in SQL Server.

Comment: @René: `SQL Server` has a concept of `schema` too. In the three-part name `'mydb.dbo.mytable'`, `mydb` is a database (physical grouping), while `dbo` is a schema (logical grouping).

Answer (score 1):

Oracle schemas are like My Documents folders in the Windows OS. A user can grant permissions to other users to see things in their schema but an Oracle schema is essentially a user's workspace.

MS SQL Server's schemas are namespaces. While you can have Accounting and Marketing schemas, they are not tightly-coupled to individual users. Objects in an Accounting schema contain accounting information and objects in the Marketing schema have marketing information.

Oracle schemas are tightly-coupled to users and MS SQL Server schemas are primarily for classification.