# What is the difference between an Oracle and Microsoft schema?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-schema

Is this an accurate way to describe the difference in the meaning of schemas between the two technologies?

- An Oracle schema is associated with a single user and consists of the objects owned by the user.
- A MS SQL Server schema is a namespace.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Oracle schemas are like My Documents folders in the Windows OS. A user can grant permissions to other users to see things in their schema but an Oracle schema is essentially a user's workspace.

MS SQL Server's schemas are namespaces. While you can have Accounting and Marketing schemas, they are not tightly-coupled to individual users. Objects in an Accounting schema contain accounting information and objects in the Marketing schema have marketing information.

Oracle schemas are tightly-coupled to users and MS SQL Server schemas are primarily for classification.

See this question for more information: [Difference between SQL Server and Oracle user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811624/difference-between-sql-server-and-oracle-user)